# Processing interleaved samples

Tags: c, audio

There is a code that accepts samples. They were originally mono, I interleaved them to stereo on generation. Now they are filtered with the following function, but I don't know hot to properly iterate by left and right channels now, since it was designed for mono samples.

`int32 *in` is the buffer that is now stereo. `int32 *out` is the filtered buffer for final output.

```
#define SQ2NCOEFFS 1024
mrindex = (SQ2NCOEFFS + 1) << 16;
mrratio = (PAL ? (int64)(PAL_CPU * 65536) : (int64)(NTSC_CPU * 65536)) / rate;
int32 count = 0;
for (x = mrindex; x < max; x += mrratio) {
    int32 acc = 0, acc2 = 0;
    unsigned int c;
    int32 *S, *D;
    for (c = SQ2NCOEFFS, S = &in[(x >> 16) - SQ2NCOEFFS], D = sq2coeffs; c; c--, D++) {
        acc += (S[c] * *D) >> 6;
        acc2 += (S[1+c] * *D) >> 6;
    }
    acc = ((int64)acc * (65536 - (x & 65535)) + (int64)acc2 * (x & 65535)) >> (16 + 11);
    *out = acc;
    out++;
    count++;
}
```

Comment: un-interleave the two streams, store into buffers and filter on each buffer. Then re-interleave.

Comment: This may help: http://blog.bjornroche.com/2013_05_01_archive.html